# Solving $\lim_{x\to2^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-3}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}-x-1}$

Tags: limits

I need to solve $$\lim_{x\to2^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-3}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}-x-1}$$ without using L'hopital or taylor. tried Conjugate multiplication to no end. Any ideas?

Comment: a general advice: if you see a root in the numerator, minus or plus something else, start by trying to get an expression of the form $x^2 - y^2$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should give conjugate multiplication a second chance:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-3}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}-x-1}&=\frac{(\sqrt{x+7}-3)(\sqrt{x+7}+3)(\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+x+1)}{(\sqrt{x^{2}+5}-x-1)(\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+x+1)(\sqrt{x+7}+3)}\\
&=\frac{(x-2)(\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+x+1)}{(x^2+5-(x+1)^2)(\sqrt{x+7}+3)}\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+5}+x+1}{2(\sqrt{x+7}+3)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Forgot I can and should multiply both of them :/ thx!

Answer (score 0):

My preferred is to use $\sqrt{1+h}=1+{h\over 2}+o(h)$

In our case, order one is enough and we need first to write $x=2+h$. The fraction transforms as follows

$${3\left(\sqrt{1+{h\over 9}}-1\right)\over 3\left(\sqrt{1+{4h\over 9}+{h^2\over 9}}-{h\over 3}-1\right)}$$

and this simplifies in one step into

$${{h\over 18}+o(h)\over -{h\over 9}+o(h)}=-{1\over 2}+o(1)$$

And the limit is $-{1\over 2}$